# woocommerce custom price based on quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

$productPrice = $12.00

Is it possible if productQuantity = 12 would be $productPrice = $99.00

I have used these 2 filters and also i have used dynamic pricing plugin that also not worked

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cp_add_custom_price' );
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_10');`

Please let me know this thing is possible

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes used dynamic pricing plugin. didnt work for me

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far and what is wrong with it if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can make it work with this hook

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cp_add_custom_price' );`

you can do as much customization you need want to custom price based on quantity with the above hook

```
$value['data']->price = $customPrice;
```

based on my requirement I have calculated $customPrice while adding 12 product in cart.